# Xamarin OxyPlot not showing in iOS

Tags: xamarin, oxyplot

My oxyplot chart works on Android only, on iOS nothing happens. Can you help me?

```
xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms;assembly=OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms">
<oxy:PlotView x:Name="appChart" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

Code behind is simple chart with 2 lines in AppDelegate.cs:

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PlotViewRenderer.Init();
```

Comment: Can you insert this OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Forms.Init() before 
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init()?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't fix problem. Again blank screen.